# What is the best application I can use for testing webservice?

Tags: web-services

Can any one suggest an application to test my webservices. Basically I am developing my webservice in java.**(All my webservices are signed and encrypted.)**

Thanks,

Narendra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use SOAP, try [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/)

Comment: SoapUI should work also with other type of web services, but i still haven't tested it with other type of web services, for example for REST services I use a Firefox plugin called REST Client

Comment: Can u suggest me other applicatios. I am not happy with sopaui bcz testing secured webservices is very painful.

Comment: I haven't found anything as good as SoapUI, really, it should also handle SSL and certificates, the other solutions are even more painful

Comment: What's the problem with SoapUI, I though it provided support for WS-Security and XML Encryption.